# Running "mup deploy" with mup-aws-beanstalk results in "Unable to load plugin mup-aws-beanstalk ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined"

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, referenceerror, mup

Im trying to deploy a project to AWS with Meteor Up plugin mup-aws-beanstalk. Instructions are pretty simple. Install plug in, get some info from your AWS account, modify a file with stuff related to your project, run the deploy command "mup deploy". Docs are here https://github.com/zodern/mup-aws-beanstalk/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

After running the deploy command, I get this error/output

```
    PS C:\Users\Arsla\OneDrive\Desktop\Greg\radgrad2\app\.deploy> mup deploy
Unable to load plugin mup-aws-beanstalk
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at C:\Users\Arsla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup-aws-beanstalk\lib\command-handlers.js:11:46
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arsla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup-aws-beanstalk\lib\command-handlers.js:220:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arsla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup-aws-beanstalk\lib\commands.js:8:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arsla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mup-aws-beanstalk\lib\index.js:9:18)
PS C:\Users\Arsla\OneDrive\Desktop\Greg\radgrad2\app\.deploy>
```

I tried reinstalling mup and mup-aws-beanstalk, but that didnt work. My env.MONGO_URL might be wrong, but I'm not sure how to check. The `id` and `secret` have been replaced with appropriate information.

this is the file I modded: .deploy/mup.js

```
module.exports = {
app: {
    // Tells mup that the AWS Beanstalk plugin will manage the app
    type: 'aws-beanstalk',
    name: 'radgrad2',
    path: 'C:\Users\Arsla\OneDrive\Desktop\Greg\radgrad2\app\.deploy',
    env: {
        ROOT_URL: 'http://localhost:3200/', 
        MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/radgrad2' //not sure about this, but localhost:27017 is the default local host for MongoDB
    },
    auth: {
        id: '12345', // provided by AWS
        secret: '6789' // provided by AWS
    },
    minInstances: 1
},
plugins: ['mup-aws-beanstalk']
};
```

Where should I look for the source of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for the error, and it looks like this was fixed two days ago.

https://github.com/zodern/mup-aws-beanstalk/issues/104#issuecomment-643861436

Are you running 0.6.4 of the plugin and mup 1.5? If so, then you probably want to reopen that issue.